# How to put JSON file on a local server?

Tags: python, json, ajax, node.js, localserver

I've driven myself insane for the last two hours attempting to find an answer for the issue that I'm encountering. I was trying to access a local JSON file called, data.json, which I placed inside my project directory. My console returned this error:

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I now know that I cannot access this file locally and I must do so through an external server. How does someone setup a local server with this file? Can someone please explain how to do it using python, json-server, and node,js? I am completely lost.

Here is my code:

```
$(function (){

var $orders = $("#orders");
var $name = $('#name');
var $drink = $('#drink');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    url: 'data.json',
    success: function(orders) {
      $.each(orders, function(i, order) {
        $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + order.name + ', Drink: ' + order.drink +  '</li>');
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('error loading orders');
    }
});

$('#add-order').on('click', function() {

    var order = {
        name: $name.val(),
        drink: $drink.val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'data.json',
      data: order,
      success: function(newOrder) {
        $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + newOrder.name + ', Drink: ' + newOrder.drink +  '</li>');
        },
      error: function () {
        alert("error saving order");
      }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does someone setup a local server with this file?

A very simple web server in Python can be launched with a single command.  This would allow you to fetch the contents over HTTP.

From the directory where your `data.json` file resides, you can run one of the following...

- if you are running Python 2:

  - `$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`
- or if you are running Python 3:

  - `$ python -m http.server 8000`

After launching the server, it will be listening for requests on port 8000.

You would access it by sending an HTTP GET request to localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.json)